# Ember.js - Supplying model to header view in all routes

Tags: ember.js

I have a header view which displays a list of links to course pages.

I supply the header controller with the list of course models so that it can generate the links. Here is the code in my index route.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
       return App.Course.findAll(); // finds all courses
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this.controllerFor('header').set('model', model); // sets model for the header     controller
    },
})
```

However, I need this header controller to always have the list of courses, regardless of which route the user is currently on. What is the Ember way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Index route is going to be replaced when you navigate somewhere else, removing your data. You would want to load this data in a path that will persist, such as the top level ApplicationRoute.